# I need to use a View as a 'Content Type' in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, content-type

I'm creating a view that needs to display two content types - a normal content type, and a view. The view needs to display three items in a row - the first two items of the normal content type are the first two items in the row, and the view needs to be the third.

I have tried Viewfield and Views Field View, and neither have done what I need them to do. I need to be able to add the view as one of the 'Content Types' that the view is picking up.

Is there a way to do this Viewception?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm getting this right, you need a view to display a normal content type, and then a view along with it?

You can always make a view of the content type, and then attach another view to it.

What is the source of the attached view's data?

Answer (score 0):

man dont do this, it will be very slow query and it will kill your webserver after a few page requests

you need to build this as a custom block with a custom query (or event multiple queries), but also check your query speed. leave me a message when you need help with building custom block or building the query